# Access-VBA SQL Query Database and Update ListBox with results

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So I have do a lot of questioning around, looking online, and all over the web and I am more than likely being blind, but I'm out of ideas.

To break down my problem, i have the following:

Contained within form "Troubleshoot" is the following

- 2 comboboxes named "cboManfact" and "cboModel"
- 1 listbox named "lstSolutions"
- 1 button named "HomeReturn"
- 1 button named "db_Search"

Contained within table "Solutions" i have the following Fields

- ID
- ManufacturerSolution
- ModelSolution
- DateSolution
- UserSolution
- SolutionText

Now the complicated part.

"lstSolutions" needs to display "SolutionText" however there is a catch.

"cboManfact" and "cboModel" contain the list of manufacturers and model numbers stored in a seperate table which works perfectly.

what i need to have. Is "lstSolutions" display "SolutionText" only when "cboManfact" text and "cboModel" text match an entry in the solutions table.

So for instance:

- cboManfact = Turbo
- cboModel = 1600

On clicking the "db_Search" button, "lstSolutions" is populated with all results for "SoltionText" where "ManufacturerSolution" = "cboManfact" and "ModelSolution" = "cboModel"

The problem with the SQL query i currently have is that it populates the list box with every result from "Solutions" but upon clicking the "db_search" button which performs a requery, the list box empties so i dont think the SQL command makes sure that cbomanfact etc match.

Here is what i have at the moment:

**lstSolutions recordSource:**

```
SELECT [SolutionText] FROM [Solutions] WHERE solutions.ManufacturerSolution like forms![Troubleshoot]!cboManfact & "*" AND solutions.ModelSolution like forms![Troubleshoot]!cboModel & "*"
```

**db_click code:**

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()
     me.lstSolutuions.requery
end sub
```

If anyone has any ideas, or has a better way of explaining this it would help. I have had help from LiamH on a seperate thread which has helped majorly but i created this in order to explain the issue clearer hopefully.

I understand to an extent what is going on now, but Im just not experienced enough to work around this myself and would like any ideas of what people would suggest.

Comment: Try to use Me.ReCalc

Comment: The list box displays the "SolutionText" field until i input stuff into the comboboxes and click the "db_click" the list box depopulates. Can you see any issues with the SQL command? :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using the following code on button click:

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()

Dim ManfactQuery As String
Dim ModelQuery As String
Dim strSQL As String

ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact.Column(1)
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel.Column(1)

If Nz(ManfactQuery) = "" Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ModelSolution = '" & ModelQuery & "'"

Else

If Nz(ModelQuery) = "" Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = '" & ManfactQuery & "'"

Else

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = " & ManfactQuery & " AND [Solutions].ModelSolution = " & ModelQuery & ""

End If

End If

Me.lstSolution.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```